# How to simplify this "if" condition?

Tags: excel, vba

its me again with another probably trivial question...

is there any way how to simplify (loop?) this condition?

The porpose of this is to make my X-axis label more clear to read rather than how it currently looks

[image: example]

My source data are in following format starting with 2015/Q4,2016/Q1,2016/Q2...up to most recent quater

"=IF(RC[-1]=""2015/Q4"",""2015" & Chr(10) & "Q4""",IF(RC[-1]=""2016/Q1"",""2016" & Chr(10) & "Q1"" ... and so on

Comment: How about a `SUBSTITUTE`?

Comment: I suppose Substitute would indeed be faster than LEFT/RIGHT, you can post your answer instead @BigBen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like:

```
"=LEFT(RC[-1],4) & Chr(10) & RIGHT(RC[-1],2)"
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the tips, however LEFT/RIGHT was also one of my solutions before I posted, but it for some reasone does not acknowledge the & Chr(10) & part (unlike the if above) - dont know why

Comment: edit: looks like that the issue was language mutation of my excel, its working now

Comment: While I appreciate the checkmark, I do believe BigBen/Dominique's answer is better in this case :)

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(I3,"/",CHAR(10))
```

Bigben proposed the function, but not the replacement character.

Comment: thanks will try that out as well!